# How to automatically update the status field in the object after its value gets changed in the picklist in visualforce?

Tags: visualforce

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="TaskListController">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="ToDo List">
     <apex:pageBlockButtons >
      <apex:commandButton value="SAVE" action="{!save}" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tasks}" var="task">
          <apex:column value="{!task.Account_Name__c}"/>
          <apex:column >
              <apex:outputLink value="/{!task.id}">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!task.Subject__c}">
                    </apex:outputText>
              </apex:outputLink>
          </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Status" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!task.Status__c}"/>
                </apex:column>  

       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class TaskListController {


    public List<To_Do__c> tasks {get;set;}

    public TaskListController(){

    tasks = [SELECT Account_Name__c, Subject__c, Status__c from To_Do__c];

       }

   public void save(){

   update tasks;
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is your picklist in your vf? This is pretty straight forward with a rerender

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `actionSupport` onchange event to call `save()` method of Controller. Also, rerender the form.

```
<apex:column headerValue="Status" >
    <apex:inputField id="statusId" value="{!task.Status__c}"> 
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="form1" action="{!save}" />
    </apex:inputField>
</apex:column>
```

For more information, refer [apex:actionSupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm)